# Custom TableViewCell imageView frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

My custom TableViewCell has a imageView defined in storyboard with frame(195, 16; 95,25)

[image]

But when I trying to access the frame at run time, it returns (0, 58, 0, 0) for all the outlets, not just the imageView, but UILabels too.

```
//CustomTableViewCell subclass
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.fiveStartForeground);
}
```

and this come out of console:

```
2012-09-27 18:57:46.563 200Pomodoros[11395:c07] <UIImageView: 0x7599640; frame = (0 58; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x759a0d0>>
```

but after a while, it gets normal again:

```
2012-09-27 18:58:48.025 200Pomodoros[11395:c07] <UIImageView: 0x7599640; frame = (195.5 16; 94.5 25); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x759a0d0>>
```

I need to change the image frame (width) in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

so that it looks like it's a 5 start rating thing.
But the frame I get then is wrong.(0, 58, 0, 0)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the stupid AutoLayout for iOS6... disable that, and you are good to go.

Comment: Maybe the frame data in size inspector is on base of window. You couldn't get it like that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the AutoLayout thing, because it is fine right after i get its frame. the layout isn't ready when I try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the first time the UI is not completely setup, so you ask for its values too soon?

Comment: But I want to make a change after it's loaded, in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath... it's not set then
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like..

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
    cell.YourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(195.5, 16, 94.5, 25); // Or what you want to set
```

I hope this will work for you..

Comment: `2012-09-27 22:04:52.465 200 frame = (195.5 16; 39.69 25); 
2012-09-27 22:04:52.472 200 frame = (195.5 16; 94.5 25); `   wired thing, it doesn't work. it set to the right frame for one second and then setting in storyboard kicks in and reset the frame.